# How to except some items from jQuery window load event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wanna exclude some items from jQuery Window load event.

I have following code:

```
$(window).on("load", function (e) {
  //do sth 
});
```

I want to do something after all resources are loaded except some specific one, for example before load some of scripts or images, the pre-loading spinner be fade out.

So in clear, the load event occurs too late because of some elements and i want to exclude them from "load time"...

Comment: You can hide elements using CSS. For more help, post your code and be more specific in your question.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette hiding an element does not prevent the element from being loaded, nor does it have an effect on the `load` event of the `window`.

Comment: @t.niese Thank u so much. :*

Comment: So in clear, the `load` event occurs too late because of some elements... And you want to exclude them from "load time" to trigger something. Is that correct?

Comment: @t.niese: I was suggesting this because of *«the pre-loading spinner be fade out»*... Which I still don't get...

Comment: I think you should be fine with `$(window).on("load"` as You will be ignoring the things which will be loaded via an async call

Comment: question is far too vague. provide  [mcve]

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette yes, i want to decrease the load time by exclude some items

Comment: What if you append the "long to load" elements later in time, using [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)?